# Is it generally possible to uniquely identify an individual MCU (for licensing purposes) (no MAC address available)

Tags: microcontroller

I am being asked to enhance the firmware installation program for an MCU (specifically, a Freescale MC9S12E64 - though I don't know if this matters).

The purpose of the enhanced installation is to limit the number of times the firmware can be installed. It seems the best way to do this would be to uniquely identify the specific MCU in use during firmware installation, in order to keep track in a central database.

If the MCU had a MAC address, this would seem to be feasible. Unfortunately, these MCU's have no network interface, and hence no MAC address. Looking through the manual for the MCU noted above, I cannot find an indication of a unique identifier for the MCU.

My question is: Do MCU's typically have unique identifiers associated with them - analogous to a MAC address - that can be obtained by software as firmware is burned into these devices?

Comment: Please do not ask the same question on multiple stack exchange sites: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15344369/is-it-generally-possible-to-uniquely-identify-an-individual-mcu-for-licensing-p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They almost all do, but they're not always accessible to the users.

I think your issue is more complex because you're trying to use it to enforce an installation. Please note that many of the DRM methods fail when a proper adversary attacks them (especially since you can't trust the microcontroller since the user has control of it).

A cursory search through the datasheet of the microcontroller failed to find any identifying serial. You should contact Freescale directly.

Comment: I've not seen many MCU's which arrive from the factory with any sort of unique serial number, it's quite an ask for a mass-produced component and they usually shout about it on the data-sheet if it has this facility. Programming your MCU at *your* factory with a unique ID, however, is very doable.

Comment: Many of the more recent ones actually do.  But as this answer points out, that's a fairly minor part of an overall scheme with gaping weaknesses, namely that once a raw binary is somehow obtained (deconstructing the software of the restricted programmer, or even snooping the signals while it does an authorized programming), that file can simply be used with a normal programmer that *just doesn't care*.  If you want to control distribution, you have to have the physical programming of devices be done by trusted parties, and hope that the readback security of the chips doesn't get defeated.

Comment: @ChrisStratton: Yep. I think a company has to watch for who could be using it. Most reputable companies wouldn't steal, but there's always someone out there that doesn't have to pay. So this has to be a multilayer solution

Comment: @ChrisStratton: If the controller offers code security and one can keep the code of a boot-loader confidential, there's no reason that an unencrypted copy of any code needs to be exposed anywhere outside the controller itself.  Even if you don't trust a company that programs parts before they go on your board, you could have the part replace its boot-loader while connected to equipment that you control; you could feed the devices unique serial numbers at that point without regard for whether the factory does.

Comment: @supercat: You're correct. But this means that there needs to be a piece of trusted equipment connected to the microcontroller. For example, the company licensing the devices needs to preprogram them. This can be difficult to do and adds more to the process.

Comment: @GustavoLitovsky: There has to be *someone* in the production pipeline whom you trust, or at minimum you have to trust that there exists a combination of people, each of whom has a piece of the puzzle, who will not put all their pieces together.  You could arrange things so that if *either* the original chip maker or some later person involved in the process is honest, you'll be fine.

Comment: @supercat: correct. But things can still be hacked. They always do. It's good enough to deter most people and force them to license, perhaps even serve as proof to a court in case of a lawsuit that they stole it.

Comment: @GustavoLitovsky Thanks for your time.  My potential client is the one creating the firmware and the software that loads it onto the MCU.  In this scenario, assuming they trust themselves, my suggested plan is to simply have the software that loads the firmware (running on a PC) require a keycode that is validated.  This would work, I think, assuming that once the firmware is installed, it can't be easily copied onto other MCU's.  Do you think the firmware is "safe" and cannot be copied?

Comment: @DanNissenbaum: The only thing the microcontroller provides is a flash security register. I don't know enough about it to say whether it protects the flash from being dumped.

Answer (score 1):

Microchip has their own system of adding unique serial numbers to mcu's. ICSP i think, In-Circuit Serial Programming. I'm not sure about Freescale. Perhaps migrating to a different mcu is the answer. In that case you could program a unique number to each unit and store them in your database.

Comment: A modifiable serial number would be of a little use to this scheme.

Answer (score 0):

The type of MCUs that have serial number will be anything that uses encryption, such as Bluetooth, workstation CPUs, such as Intel (though I understand this feature may be turned off), and of course the previously mentioned ethernet MACs, which themselves contain elaborate MCU subsystems.

The kind of technologies that can be used for a serial number are limited. In fact it may well cost more to add the serial number than the increased profitability of your licensed software. The usual techniques are:

```
efuse: a type of polysilicon which goes open circuit when a high current is passed.
floating gate transistor: uses quantum mechanical tunnelling to make a small memory.
EEPROM, EAROM, FLASH: uses extra mask layers to provide a memory function.
1-wire serial number interface: a separate chip and low cost interface.
```

All of these methods require extra masks, royalties, test time or all of the above, so are generally not implemented on mass-produced MCUs. Expensive desktop processor can absorb the cost, but there are privacy issues in paranoid countries like America.

Comment: Intel has not provided unique serials in their CPUs in over 15 years. That feature was only present on certain Pentium III CPUs between 1999 and 2001.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution to your problem could be to have  the original MCU firmware generate a random UUID at first startup, and write this to EEPROM. This UUID would then be used as a unique serial number afterwards.

This approach fails if firmware upgrades clear EEPROM, and also if the user/adversary can clear the EEPROM. However all DRM schemes can be defeated and this approach would at least stop casual/accidental firmware piracy.

There are multiple ways to generate random numbers on MCUs. If you think this solution has promise, try finding a source of noise, such as uncorellated timer sources or temperature sensors.

Answer (score -1):

According to this 1999 [STOA report](http://cryptome.org/stoa-r3-5.htm)
"The relevant committees of the European Parliament, should be asked to consider legal measures to prevent [Processor Serial Number]-equipped (or PSN-equivalent) chips from being installed in the computers of European citizens, firms and organisations."

So no, it is not generally possible to uniquely identify an individual MCU.

In my opinion, that whole decision has been made irrelevent by GSM, Smartphones, and location awareness, and was already so in 1999, but possibly the actual intention was to hurt MS and Intel: if so, it was probably successful.

Comment: As European's PCs with network interfaces have globally unique MAC addresses just like everyone else's, the applicability of this, if any at all, is limited to a very narrow definition of computer and processor which probably does not include embedded chips either.  And at least one of the major makers of embedded arm chips with hardware serial numbers is based in the EU.

Comment: Even in 1999 computers and processors had network interfaces with MAC addresses. It is specifically the reason why individual MCU's don't have PSNs. Since the OP specifically asked about MCU's, and specifically without network interface, the applicability of your comment seems limited.

Comment: No, it has very little to do with why MCU don't have hardware serial numbers, because in fact many of the more recent ones, and from European vendors at that, **do**.  If the proposal mentioned above ever gained force of law, it apparently was quite narrow in terms of what sort of "computer" / "processor" it applied to.

Comment: OK, which "many more recent ones"? Not PIC,INTEL,AMD,AVR,TI, and none of the ARM ones I use or am aware of. And apparently not ON or FREESCALE either. Yes, it was quite narrow and probably a bit stupid as noted. See my original answer above.

Comment: ST, NXP, Atmel, TI, Freescale and probably many others have unique serial numbers in many of their recent ARM MCU's.

Comment: Quote a part number.

Comment: How about you quote the part number of an arm MCU series *newly announced in the past two years* by one of those vendors, that does not?   They may exist, but they are no more numerous than those that do have unique id's.

Comment: Which you are unable to find or identify. TI AM5K2E04/02 is less than a year old. Your turn. Even if you eventually find one exception, that does not justify your false generalization.

Comment: I'm a little surprised that the recent NXP LPC1114FN28/102 ARM includes a unique device serial number.

Comment: LPC1114FN28 is specifically targeted at the eMetering market, which one way or another requires a unique ID. Hopefully this indicates a general loosening of the market, because apart from the panic and fear, even in 1999 OEM's and eCommerce wanted processor serial numbers.

Comment: That report was referring specifically to Intel's Pentium III serial number, cf. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentium_III#Controversy_about_privacy_issues

Comment: Yes, that action, targeted at Intel's cutting-edge Pentium III serial numbers, affected all [Processor Serial Number]-equipped (or PSN-equivalent) chips. Which is why there weren't, until years later, chips that inculded [Processor Serial Number]-equipped (or PSN-equivalent).